# Trap by initiramfs after a reboot from Window 10

Tags: windows, kubuntu, initramfs

I have a dual boot kubuntu / Windows 10 system. A 2 TB hard drive separated in half / half between Kubuntu and Windows 10.

Whenever I leave kubuntu to reboot on Windows 10, back to Kubuntu, my system hangs on initramfs. I ended up finding a recipe to go back to Kubuntu, but it's complicated and I'm looking for a better one.

Currently, I have to go to uefi (at the start of the computer) to allow a boot on a USB key with a copy of Kubuntu. From this copy, I manually install GParted and force a repair of the partition "/" (ext4). I go back to uefi to put back the choice that allows Grub to return to the start screen and from there I start Kubuntu.

I wish my partition remains healthy after being on Windows 10.

Regards

Comment: Seems like you are saying that Windows is corrupting your Kubuntu partition?

Comment: Sounds odd , I did not know gparted reparied anything. What do you mean buy "I manually install GParted and force a repair of the partition "/" " ?? . Is both fast boot and hibernation disabled in windows ?

Comment: I come back after some time to give the solution to my problem. The culprit is the Ext2fs application installed on Windows. Ext2fs has a bug that corrupts the Superblock and prevents Linux booting.

So the solution was to uninstall Ext2fs! Regarding the use of GParted. With the problem of the corrupt Superblock on my hard drive, I was forced to use a Kubuntu distribution on a USB key. From this Kubuntu session, I had to install GParted to fix the faulty partition on my hard drive.

Comment: What I mean by "install GParted". GParted is not part of the packages available on the live distribution. I had to get it on the repositories of ubuntu. To get there, I had to activate my Wi-Fi connection and then go through Discover to get GParted.